# Implement customizable ForeignKey in packaged Django app

Tags: python, django, packaging

Hello wonderful community,

I have a question about the best way to make a ForeignKey in a packaged Django app customizable. Apologies for the long post, the majority of it is just a detailed example. I just started with Django last week (although I have quite a lot experience with Python and packaging) and I'd highly appreciate some feedback from more experienced Django developers.

### Summary

I would like to create a Django app that can also be installed via `pip`. In this app, I create a model that holds a `ForeignKey` field which should point to a model in a different app (i.e. the target of the `ForeignKey` is not part of the developed package). My question is, what is the best way to make this target flexible?

### The buildings example

Here is an example of the principal problem (the full bash script to generate this example is at the bottom of this post). This is not my real project, but it's quite similar.

Consider a `Building` django model, that describes properties of a building. This building has a `contact` field that points to a user that is responsible for the building. i.e.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Building(models.Model):

    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I save this as a `buildings` django app and publish this app as the `django-buildings` python package. I.e. someone who wants to use the `buildings` app can simply install it via `pip install django-buildings` and add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Now, however, there might be multiple reasons why one might not want to use the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` class for this. Consider a `university` django project, for instance, that has a `people_database` app. The university might have a lot of external people in their database, that might not have an account (i.e. do not have an entry in the `auth_user` table). Instead, they have a generic `Person` model, something like

```py
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

so what is the best way to associate the `Building.contact` field with this `Person` class?

### Example script

Here is the bash script to generate the two projects, `django-buildings` and `university`. Note that it installs the newly created `django-buildings` package via `pip`. So if you want to avoid changes to your python environment, either work in a virtual (or separate conda) environment with `django` installed, or run `pip uninstall django-buildings` afterwords.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Script to generate the django-buildings example
#
# It assumes that django is installed.
set -ex

mkdir django-buildings

django-admin startproject django_buildings_test_site django-buildings

cd django-buildings
python manage.py startapp buildings

cat > setup.py << EOF
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'django-buildings',
    version = '0.1.0',
    packages=["buildings"]
)
EOF

cat > buildings/models.py << EOF
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Buildings(models.Model):

    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
EOF

echo 'INSTALLED_APPS.insert(0, "buildings")' >> django_buildings_test_site/settings.py

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

cd ..

pip install -e django-buildings

## Create university project

django-admin startproject university

cd university

python manage.py startapp people_database

cat > people_database/models.py << EOF
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
EOF

cat >> university/settings.py << EOF
INSTALLED_APPS.insert(0, "people_database")
INSTALLED_APPS.insert(0, "buildings")
EOF

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I already thought about some options, but, as I said, I am very new to Django so maybe I overlooked something and I'd highly appreciate your feedback!

#### Option 1: Subclassing the `Building`

One possibility would be to subclass the `Building` class and overwrite the `contact` somewhere inside the `university` project. I.e., `university/people_database/models.py` might look like

```py
from django.db import models
from buildings.models import Building


class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class UniversityBuilding(Building):

    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Although this would be very a standard OOP approach, it can be quite a lot of duplicated code. What if, for instance, I do not only define a `Building` model, but also a `Floor` and a `Room` within a `Building`, and all three models have a `contact` field. Then I would need to subclass all three of them.

#### Option 2: Derive `Person` from a model baseclass

Another option would be to define a `Contact` model within `buildings/models.py` and the `Person` class within the `people_database` should be a subclass of it. I.e.

`django-buildings/buildings/models.py` would look like

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Contact(models.Model):
    """A base class for building contacts"""


class Building(models.Model):

    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

and the `Person` class in `university/people_database/models.py` looks like

```py
from buildings.models import Contact

class Person(Contact):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

To me, this solution sounds much more appropriate and django-like, but I wonder whether there are pitfalls that I cannot see as a newbie.

#### Option 3: Use a `GenericForeignKey`

I could also make the `contact` a GenericForeignKey (see djangos [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)) framework. I.e. the `Building` model would look like

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Building(models.Model):

    contact_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    contact = GenericForeignKey('contact_type', 'object_id')
```

although this would be possible and very generic, it would be an exaggeration with a lot of negative consequences (from what I red so far about `GenericForeignKey`s, see [realpython](https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/#generic-foreign-key) for instance).

### My suggestion

Probably Option 2 would be the best? Or is there any better approach?